# What does `wedge` means in vcglib?

Tags: mesh, meshlab, vcg

In [the Visualization and Computer Graphics Library (VCG for short)](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/vcglib/), there's a concept as `wedge`.
For example, [`vcg::face::WedgeTexCoord`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/vcglib/html/classvcg_1_1face_1_1WedgeTexCoord.html) and [`vcg::face::WedgeColor`](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/vcglib/html/classvcg_1_1face_1_1WedgeColor.html). What does  `wedge` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*wedge* means one of the corner portion of a triangle. You can imagine that attributes of a mesh (color, normal texture coords) can be stored there in a way that can allow to manage easily discontinuities and smooth variations. In this way a face store the colors for his three vertices independently.

I think the first widely use of this term is in this paper:

Hoppe, Hugues. "New quadric metric for simplifying meshes with appearance attributes." Proceedings Visualization'99 (Cat. No. 99CB37067). IEEE, 1999.
([PDF](http://hhoppe.com/newqem.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for the reference! For other's convenience, the paper stated: "*a vertex is partitioned into k>=1 wedges, each wedge `w_i` having its own attribute vector `s_i`.* "